# AngularJS trigger ng-change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just want to simply trigger a change whenever I click a button. The change will just alert a text. However the trigger does not work please help.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="first.name"> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="same" id="sames" ng-change="sameAsAbove(first, second)"> Same as above <br />
    <select ng-model="change" id="changes" ng-change="changeOver()">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="second.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="second.school"> 
    <span ng-click="clickMe()">Click Me!</span>
    <!-- <span id="clickMe">Click Me!</span> -->
    {{ same  }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.sameAsAbove = function(primary, receiver){
          receiver['name'] = primary['name'];
        };
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
         angular.element(document.getElementById('changes')).triggerHandler('change');
         // x = angular.element(document.getElementById('changes')).val();
         // alert(x);
        }
        $scope.changeOver = function(){
          alert("deam");
        }
      });
      $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        // alert("czxvzx");
        // $("#same").trigger("click");
        $("#changes").change();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zErS4DaTgR79SBLbtGOy?p=preview

Comment: Describe in the question where the exact problem is, please.

Comment: Two answers has already  been given so others has understood it

Comment: The question has to be useful to the community as a whole. If 1% people understand your question and 99% don't or think your question has issues, those 99% are going to downvote. So try to make your question as clear as you can.

Comment: It's obviously clear, "I just want to simply trigger a change whenever I click a button. The change will just alert a text", is this statement not clear to you? Is the code not clear to you as well?

Comment: Well, it's not clear where exactly your symptom lies. Which button? Which change? Where in the code is it? You can't expect a user to find that out if you just say 'I click a button and it's not working'. What's your button supposed to do, exactly, that it's not doing?

Comment: You're just having a hard time to understand,, it's so simple. An answer is given to me, note more than 5 minutes and you're still stuck trying to understand the question. You are so funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$timeout){
        $scope.sameAsAbove = function(primary, receiver){
          receiver['name'] = primary['name'];
        };
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
         $timeout(function() {
                      angular.element(document.getElementById('changes')).triggerHandler('change');
  }, 100);

         // x = angular.element(document.getElementById('changes')).val();
         // alert(x);
        }
        $scope.changeOver = function(){
          alert("deam");
        }
      });
      $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        // alert("czxvzx");
        // $("#same").trigger("click");
        $("#changes").change();
      });
    </script>
```

By adding $timeout your problem get resolved.

Comment: This is surprising! How did $timeout solved the case?

Comment: because at that time event was not binded, so angular needs to wait for event to bind and that's it your issue resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:-

```
$scope.clickMe = function(){
        var scope = angular.element("#changes").scope();
         scope.changeOver();
         //angular.element(document.getElementById('changes')).triggerHandler('change');

}
```

Working copy [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLU0JXd8zL620FLWMHH7?p=preview)